# What word describes words that can be more that one part of speech?

Tags: word-request, parts-of-speech

Some words, depending on how they're used, can be used as different parts of speech.

i.e a **noun** in one case and a **verb** in another.

---

#### Examples

Here's a couple examples: Top, Quiet, Fast

- **Top**

  - > *noun* in *"the spinning **top** fell over"*
  - > *adjective* in *"the **top** shelf"*
- **Quiet**

  - > *adjective* in *"she's a **quiet** person"*
  - > *noun* in *"I need peace and **quiet**"* or *"please keep quiet"*
- **Fast**

  - > *noun* in *"they completed a two day **fast**"*
  - > *adjective* in *"the new car is **fast**"*

#### What are these types of words called?

Comment: As the others have said, there is no specific term for words that belong to more than one part of speech.

Comment: see also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46277/what-word-can-fulfill-the-most-parts-of-speech

Comment: @MichaelRybkin No, the reason homophones is called homo**phone**s is they have the same pronunciation. Most of them do not have the same spelling or origin. You might be thinking **homonyms** or **polysemes**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process itself is called "**conversion**" or "**zero derivation**" . It refers to the process of changing a word's part of speech without any change to its morphology.

> Conversion normally involves changing a word's syntactic category
>   without any concomitant change of form, as in the creation of the verb
>   humble from the adjective humble or of the noun attempt from the verb
>   attempt

*from Huddleston, R, and GK Pullum. 2002. The Cambridge Grammar of English. Cambridge*

The words that experience conversion may be referred to as **"zero-derived words"**.

There are words like **record** or **permit** which can be used as a noun or verb. They have the same spellings and the same (or lets say related) meanings, but the stress is moved to a different syllable, so they are a little different in pronunciation. This process is called **["initial-stress-derivation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial-stress-derived_noun)**:

> Initial-stress derivation is a phonological process in English that
>   moves stress to the first syllable of verbs when they are used as
>   nouns or adjectives. (This is an example of a suprafix.) This process
>   can be found in the case of several dozen verb-noun and verb-adjective
>   pairs and is gradually becoming more standardized in some English
>   dialects, but it is not present in all. The list of affected words
>   differs from area to area, and often depends on whether a word is used
>   metaphorically or not. At least 170 verb-noun or verb-adjective pairs
>   exist. Some examples are:
>
> - record: as a verb, "Remember to recórd the show!".
> - record: as a noun, "I'll keep a récord of that request."

Comment: That's the process used to form such words. But there is no specific term for the words themselves that belong to more than one part of speech.

Comment: @BillJ Yes, I have mentioned that it's the name of the process, not the word. However, the word may be called a *zero-derived word*.

Comment: That term does not describe those items that belong to more than one word category by virtue of their function. We're talking about a term that would cover, say, "early", which can be both an adjective and an adverb. I've never come across such a term, and I don't believe one exists.

Comment: @BillJ conversible / zero-derived means that a word can be a noun or verb depending on context. I believe that's exactly what I was looking for. I would've liked a single noun-world for such a term, but I feel this is about as close as we'll get it.

Comment: @DannyDannyDanny No, again, that's a process. or formation, not a term for words that belong to more than one category.

Comment: Sorry, but I feel this answer is wrong. "Zero derivation" can only describe two words when one word is ***derived*** from the other, or when both are derived from the same root word. It may describe a couple of the OP's examples, such as the two uses of *quiet*, but the example of "fast" to mean both a high speed and abstaining from food are two entirely unrelated words. Take "pen" as another example - the writing implement is derived from the Latin *penna* whereas an animal enclosure is derived from old English *penn*. One is not a derivation of the other.

Comment: @Astralbee According to [this source](https://www.thoughtco.com/conversion-functional-shift-in-grammar-1689925) and also the one I have mentioned in my post, "In English grammar, conversion is a word-formation process that *assigns an existing word to a different word class (part of speech) or syntactic category.*" This process is also known as a functional shift or *zero derivation*.

Comment: @Astralbee  Although some of the OP's examples may seem unrelated, I think the OP is looking for the process of conversion as it's mentioned in the question, and he has approved in the comment section that it's exactly what he is looking for. However, I admit that "zero-derived words" may not be a general term for these words, but I think it can be used for the words of one category (For example, when we are only talking about the word "attempt" or any other similar words)

Comment: @helen Yes I understand what "conversion" is too. It is a process. So for the relationship between two words to be described by this process they both have to be involved in it. My previous comment explains that some words in the OP's examples may not have been a result of such a process and there are other homonyms which definitely have not. I'm aware the OP has accepted it. That's one of the flaws of this site, the askers tend not to speak English natively and so they can't really be completely certain about what is wrong or right. They will find out when they fail their English exams.

Answer (score 0):

Your examples above are all *homonyms*. Homonyms are words that are spelled *and* pronounced the same but have different meanings.

Taking "top" as a single example; as a noun it can be used to describe an item of clothing (in UK English anyway) and obviously that is something entirely different to a "spinning top". So what you have are two different things that are spelled *and* pronounced the same. The fact they have the same root meaning is certainly relevant, but doesn't make them the same.

One comment suggested that they are "homophones", but that isn't completely accurate if they are spelled the same. True, a homonym is also by definition a homophone, but two words can be considered homophones if they simply *sound* the same (for example *sea* and *see*). If they are spelled and sound the same they are homonyms.

- **Homophone** - words that *sound* the same but have different meanings. (eg "sea" and "see")
- **Homograph** - words that are *spelled* the same but have different meanings. (eg "wind" as in windmill, and "wind" as in the long and winding road)
- **Homonym** - words that are *spelled and sound* the same but have different meanings. (eg "fly" as in insect, or to travel by air)

The reason I feel this is the most appropriate answer is because "*homonym*" accurately describes the words above regardless of whether or not they are different *word classes* (what you call "parts of speech", eg nouns, adjectives, etc).

Also two words can be described as homonyms whether or not the words have the same *derivation*. For example, "mine" as a noun for an underground excavation is of French or possibly Celtic origin. The adjective "mine" meaning to dig such an excavation is clearly derived from it. However, "*mine*" as a possessive pronoun is of Germanic origin, so it *cannot be referred to as a derivation*. However, all three are *homonyms*.

Comment: That's not what the OP asked about. They wanted to know about words that belong to more than one part of speech.

Comment: Strictly speaking, _fast_ and _quiet_ in the OP's examples are **polysemes**, not really homonyms sensu stricto. That being said, sometimes polysemes are also referred to as **polysemous homonyms**.

Comment: @EddieKal The two examples of "fast" given by the OP are not polysemes as they have entirely different meanings, and possibly even have entirely different roots.

Comment: @Astralbee Yep, just "_quiet_". TIL: when making a comment at the bottom of a really long page, I better scroll up to double-check. I misremembered that the OP had _fast_ down as _adjective_ and _adverb_. In fact, they meant noun and adjective, while writing down noun and adverb. Just fixed the question.